# How to create a modified copy of a File object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, copy, clone

Properties of files received from an `<input type="file">` are read-only.

For example, the following attempt to re-write `file.name` would either fail silently or throw `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#<File>'`.

```html
<input onchange="onchange" type="file">
```

```js
onchange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    file.name = 'foo';
}
```

Attempting to create a copy via `Object.assign({}, file)` fails (creates an empty object).

So how does one clone a `File` object?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My solution lay in the `File` constructor:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Implementation_notes

Which itself is an extension of `Blob`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

```js
let file = event.target.files[0];
if (this.props.distro) {
    const name = 'new-name-here' + // Concat with file extension.
        file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.'));
    // Instantiate copy of file, giving it new name.
    file = new File([file], name, { type: file.type });
}
```

Note the first argument to `File()` must be an array, not simply the original file.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `FormData.prototype.append()`, which also converts a `Blob` to a `File` object.

```
let file = event.target.files[0];
let data = new FormData();
data.append("file", file, file.name);
let _file = data.get("file");
```

Answer (score 6):

## A more cross browser solution

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41008025/1889273) works for me too in modern browsers, but unfortunately it does not work in IE11, since [IE11 does not support the `File` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File).
However, IE11 does support the `Blob` constructor so it can be used as an alternative.

For example:

```
var newFile  = new Blob([originalFile], {type: originalFile.type});
newFile.name = 'copy-of-'+originalFile.name;
newFile.lastModifiedDate = originalFile.lastModifiedDate;
```

Source: [MSDN - How to create a file instannce using HTML 5 file API?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9daae67a-f3f6-4359-a42b-1e0c7e50ed44/how-to-create-a-file-instannce-using-html-5-file-api?forum=iewebdevelopment)