# How to create File Object in client side Javascript for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, client-side-validation

I am using mocha, chai, karma along with PhantomJS and related addons. How can we create a client side File object to pass it to FileReader API ? I have to upload a test jpeg file, create a file object and pass it to FileReader api to continue testing.

Comment: @guest271314: I don't think this is a duplicate. That question is about reading/writing local files. This question is about stubbing or mocking the `File` object for testing purposes. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @GregBurghardt OP is asking how to create a `File` object. See also [Chrome: Create file input from blob with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739946/chrome-create-file-input-from-blob-with-javascript)

Comment: I agree with Greg Burghardt, This question is indeed about stubbing but with a valid file instead of some arrays containing values. I want to create a File object for a valid image.

Comment: @DeepanPrabhuBabu _"I want to create a File object"_ You can create a `File` object using `new File()` constructor, as described at Answer at linked Question; or `FormData,prototype.append()` [How to create a modified copy of a File object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008024/how-to-create-a-modified-copy-of-a-file-object-in-javascript/)

Comment: @DeepanPrabhuBabu [JavaScript - New File() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116513/javascript-new-file-not-working/)

Comment: @guest271314: Again, the answers you keep posting in comments show how to **create** the File object, and not how they should or could be used in the context unit testing. Just creating the object isn't enough. It must act the same way as a real `File` when passing it to the code under test. Those other questions don't address those concerns.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Voted to reopen. Though not entirely sure what expected result is? The Question is still "How to create File Object in client side Javascript for unit testing?".  The linked Questions provide Answers directly related to how to create `File` object client side. Am curious now as to in which ways the present Question will explore `File` object other than approaches present in linked Questions.

Comment: @DeepanPrabhuBabu Not certain what issue you are having? What problems are you encountering creating a `File` object at client side `javascript` Can you include the `javascript` which you have tried to resolve the issues you are encountering at Question?

Comment: @DeepanPrabhuBabu: Can you post the code you are already using to create this mock or stub?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you need a File instance, A Blob should be enough. You need to show us some more context on what you are trying to achieve.
What are your code doing and what is the test expected to yield?

If you have access to DOM and canvas just simply create one with js

```js
document.createElement('canvas').toBlob(function(blob) {
  // FileReader will be happy with just a blob
  // But if you really want a file you need to construct it also
  // var file = new File([blob], 'canvas.jpg', {type: blob.type})
  
  var fr = new FileReader
  fr.onload = function(){
    console.log(fr.result.byteLength)
  }
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
}, 'image/jpeg')
```

Comment: Dev code I am writing is going to validate files using javascript FileReader on a client's browser, once he selects a file for upload in a form, before uploading though. Basically, my setup consists of npm, karma, mocha, chai, browserify, phantomjs, and javascript code to validate a file, once a file object is passed. The code is working if I use a vanilla browser and select a file manually. I want to convert this into an automated test, where i can parameterize the file and pass different test files to test the code flow. Please tell me if you need more context.

Comment: I am unable to test using phantomjs completely, because it doesn't fire most of the onload methods, and moreover, blob object i created using your above code ( Thank you !! ) is empty. I used a polyfill as phantomjs did not support natively.

Comment: @DeepanPrabhuBabu _"and javascript code to validate a file, once a file object is passed.The code is working if I use a vanilla browser and select a file manually. I want to convert this into an automated test, where i can parameterize the file and pass different test files to test the code flow."_ Are you trying to populate the `.files` object of an `<input type="file">` element using `javascript`? Can you include the `javascript` that both is, and is not returning expected result at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask