# How to deeply clone state in React where file was attached?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state in some component, where i want to store file for upload in the future.

i'm cloning the state with:

```
const formClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.agentForm))
```

**Here is the state of agentForm for one field for example**

```
authEmail: {fieldType: "input", config: {…}, validation: {…}, value: "", valid: false, …}
```

**Also, here is a state of field avatar. Please pay attention to the value object!**

```
avatar:
config: {label: "Аватар", icon: "ellipsis-v", filetypesAccept: "image/*", storageRef: "avatars"}
error: ""
fieldType: "inputFile"
touched: false
url: "blob:http://localhost:3000/aaba2b6a-7646-4172-b634-09844a0a7272"
valid: true
validation: {required: false, pattern: ""}
value: File {name: "176B8704.jpg", lastModified: 1556695374835, lastModifiedDate: Wed May 01 2019 10:22:54 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 11340510, …}
__proto__: Object
```

**When i'm calling** `const formClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.agentForm))`

i have deep clone of the state, **BUT** i have value of avatar field `value: {}`

So as i can see, this function doesn't make deep clone of avatar file, where it is a file.

**Question is: How to deeply clone value of avatar from the state?**

Answer (score 0):

So i have found workaround with this topic [How to create a modified copy of a File object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008024/how-to-create-a-modified-copy-of-a-file-object-in-javascript)

Simply to create a new file, but with same name